# MOXy: Efficient deep copy of JAXBElement

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, docx4j

docx4j v3.3.0 uses the following code to clone a JAXB object:

```
    public static <T> T deepCopy(T value, JAXBContext jc) {

    if (value==null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't clone a null argument");
    }

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) value.getClass();
        JAXBElement<T> contentObject = new JAXBElement<T>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, value);
        JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, contentObject);
        JAXBElement<T> elem = jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(source, clazz);

        T res;
        if (value instanceof JAXBElement<?>) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T resT = (T) elem;
            res = resT;
        } else {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T resT = (T) elem.getValue();
            res = resT;
        }

        return res;
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
    }
}
```

With MOXy v2.5.2 (which we use, since it supports Java 6) and the latest 2.6.3, attempting to clone a JAXBElement, for example:

```
public void testIssue212() {

    CTBookmark bookmark = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTBookmark();
    JAXBElement<CTBookmark> el =Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createBodyBookmarkStart(bookmark);

    Object o = XmlUtils.deepCopy(el);
}
```

results in:

```
    [Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
    Exception Description: A descriptor for class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:980)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:303)
        at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.deepCopy(XmlUtils.java:974)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
    Exception Description: A descriptor for class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.descriptorNotFoundInProject(XMLMarshalException.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.getSession(Context.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:795)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context.getSession(Context.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:655)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:301)
        ... 26 more
```

We can workaround this with something like:

```
        JAXBElement<T> elem; 

        if (Context.getJaxbImplementation().equals(JAXBImplementation.ECLIPSELINK_MOXy)
                && value instanceof JAXBElement<?>) {

            elem = (JAXBElement<T>) value;
            Class<?> valueClass = elem.getDeclaredType();

            Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(256);
            mar.marshal(elem, bout);

            Unmarshaller unmar = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            elem = (JAXBElement<T>)unmar.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    bout.toByteArray())), valueClass);

        }
```

but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) that includes the `Copyable Plugin`´ which I think fits the task pretty well.

You may be interested `Copyable Plugin`, it generates reflection-free strategic copy methods.

Activation in Maven (see also [Using JAXB2 Basics Plugins](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins)):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The plugin then generates deep, reflection-free and strategy-based `clone` and `copyTo` methods (see below). This gives you very efficient copying. You can also "copy" to an existing instance or customize what and how should be copied by specifying your own strategy. For instance, you may want to avoid copying `id` fields or something like that. Generated code also knows how to deal with `JAXBElement`.

This is a kind of code generated:

```
public Object clone() {
    return copyTo(createNewInstance());
}

public Object copyTo(Object target) {
    final CopyStrategy2 strategy = JAXBCopyStrategy.INSTANCE;
    return copyTo(null, target, strategy);
}

public Object copyTo(ObjectLocator locator, Object target, CopyStrategy2 strategy) {
    final Object draftCopy = ((target == null)?createNewInstance():target);
    if (draftCopy instanceof IssueJIIB35) {
        final IssueJIIB35 copy = ((IssueJIIB35) draftCopy);
        {
            Boolean nameShouldBeCopiedAndSet = strategy.shouldBeCopiedAndSet(locator, this.isSetName());
            if (nameShouldBeCopiedAndSet == Boolean.TRUE) {
                String sourceName;
                sourceName = this.getName();
                String copyName = ((String) strategy.copy(LocatorUtils.property(locator, "name", sourceName), sourceName, this.isSetName()));
                copy.setName(copyName);
            } else {
                if (nameShouldBeCopiedAndSet == Boolean.FALSE) {
                    copy.name = null;
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    return draftCopy;
}

public Object createNewInstance() {
    return new IssueJIIB35();
}
```

Might look a bit weird/cumbersome but it takes quite a few JAXB peculiarities into account.

Comment: thanks for this.  iirc, i had trouble in the past trying to use multiple extensions at once.  docx4j uses parent-pointer-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the docx4j code introduced in https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/pull/163 had issues copying a JAXBElement, whether using MOXy or Sun/Oracle reference implementation.

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/b5d8b4722e814945e502da9f0516d59c498b64bb fixes it